# Probabilistic behavior of greedy point selection in the plane

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, asymptotics

Let $\mathcal{X} = X_1,\dots,X_n$ be a collection of independent, uniform samples in the unit square.  Let $\mathcal{S}=\{X_1\}$, and consider the following process:  for $i=2,\dots,n$, let $x^*$ be the element of $\mathcal{X}$ that is as far as possible from all points in $\mathcal{S}$, i.e. $$x^{*}=\arg\max_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\min_{s\in\mathcal{S}}\|x-s\|$$
and add $x^*$ to $\mathcal{S}$.  My question is:  at each iteration of this process, probabilistically speaking, what is the distance from $x^*$ to its nearest point in $\mathcal{S}$?  Below I show a plot for $n=1000$.
[image: Plot of this process]

UPDATE:  I think that the scaling of this process looks like the following:  when you add the $i$th point, the distance is proportional to $\sqrt{\frac{1-i/n}{i/n}}$.  The picture below shows the ratio between my observed distances and this proposed proportionality:

[image]

Comment: It is clear that it is something like $c/\sqrt m$ for quite a while (say, for $m<n/2$), so it would be more interesting to see the graph of that distance times the square root. I have no guess about what the correct $c$ might be though...

Comment: Note that this process is creating the minimum spanning tree of the set of random points (due to Prim’s algorithm). This is something that’s classically studied which might lead to helpful links.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal I don't think it's quite that, I would have to replace the "max" with another "min":  $x^{*}=\arg\min_{x\in\mathcal{X}\setminus\mathcal{S}}\min_{s\in\mathcal{S}}\|x-s\|$

Comment: Can you say what exactly you are graphing?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Apparently the distance at step $m$ against $m$ though I'm not sure whether the included graph represents just a single trial or the average over some number of trials (the latter would be more interesting to see, of course). You can easily program something like that yourself :-)

Comment: @YuvalPeres fedja is correct, and I confess that I only did the one trial.  Updated with a proposed scaling law.